# Trying max() function on datetime field of format dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

I am trying to create a calculated field where i am using a column ,called "requestdatetime" and it is of data type **datetime**, to find the latest date .
Thus i used the function :  max({requestdatetime}), but i am getting an entire column displaying "unavailable".
The format of this datetime column is : dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z , example (2023-05-25T00:04:35.000Z).

I suspect that max() function is unable to convert this column due to format.
I have checked for nulls, there are none.

Comment: Either the field is a `datetime` field - and in that case it does not have a format - or it is a `string` that is a formatted `datetime` value. Which is it?

Comment: When i imported the dataset into quicksight, it considered the column as a string. Then i changed the column to date time and used the format dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z . Then quicksight was able to consider the column as datetime data type. And i am basing my calculation field on the fact the that the column is datetime data type. IS there something that i am doing wrong.

Comment: If it is a `datetime` then you can perform calculations on it. I suspect you're still working with the `string` and not the `datetime`.

Comment: if it was string the max() function wouldnt have run in the first place. I have attached a pic above. It seems like that it is converting it to datetime type, but it is unavailable for some reason